# Why i am unable to add text in the scene even though my code seems to to correct?

Tags: three.js

I am just a beginner who is trying to learn three.js , while i was tryig to add a text in the scene , it is not getting added . i dont know what is the problem . Can anyone please help me with the code?

```
const fontloader = new FontLoader()fontloader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json' ,(font) =>{const TextMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();const  textGeometry = new TextBufferGeometry('Hello World',{font: font,size: 0.5,height: 0.2,curveSegments: 12,bevelEnabled:true,bevelSize: 0.02,bevelOffset:0,bevelSegments: 5});
```

```
const text = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, TextMaterial);scene.add(text);});
```

---

Here is the full source code of my .js file:

```
import './style.css'
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js'
import GUI from 'lil-gui'; 
import { FontLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FontLoader.js';
import{ TextGeometry} from 'three/examples/jsm/geometries/TextGeometry.js';
/**
 * Base
*/
// Debug
const gui = new GUI();

// Canvas
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas.webgl')

// Scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene()

/**
 * Textures
*/
// const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader()

/**
 * Object
 */
const cube = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()
    )

scene.add(cube)
//font
const fontloader = new FontLoader()
fontloader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json' ,
    (font) =>{
        const TextMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
        const  textGeometry = new TextBufferGeometry(
            'Hello World',
            {
                font: font,
                size: 0.5,
                height: 0.2,
                curveSegments: 12,
                bevelEnabled:true,
                bevelSize: 0.02,
                bevelOffset:0,
                bevelSegments: 5
            });
    

const text = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, TextMaterial);
scene.add(text);
});



/**
 * Sizes
 */
const sizes = {
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
}

window.addEventListener('resize', () =>
{
    // Update sizes
    sizes.width = window.innerWidth
    sizes.height = window.innerHeight
    
    // Update camera
    camera.aspect = sizes.width / sizes.height
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    
    // Update renderer
    renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
    renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))
})

/**
 * Camera
*/
// Base camera
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, sizes.width / sizes.height, 0.1, 100)
camera.position.x = 1
camera.position.y = 1
camera.position.z = 2
scene.add(camera)

// Controls
const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, canvas)
controls.enableDamping = true

/**
 * Renderer
 */
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    canvas: canvas
})
renderer.setSize(sizes.width, sizes.height)
renderer.setPixelRatio(Math.min(window.devicePixelRatio, 2))


/**
 * Animate
 */
const clock = new THREE.Clock()

const tick = () =>
{
    const elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime()

    // Update controls
    controls.update()
    
    // Render
    renderer.render(scene, camera)

    // Call tick again on the next frame
    window.requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

tick()
```

I wanted to add to the text in the scene but its not happening

Answer (score 0):

You are importing TextGeometry which is the correct geometry, but you are using TextBufferGeometry.